# How do I make a div appear after making a choice in a datalist?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code for a fieldset. Now I want when you have made a choice between "*Als een stage bedrijf*" or "*voor een project*". There appears my div. In my css is my div at the moment display: none, but it has to change in display:inline when you made a choice between these two.

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Ik wil mijn aanmelden:</legend>
            <input type="text" id="Ik wil mijn aanmelden voor:" list="keuzes">
                <datalist id="keuzes">
                    <option value="Als Stage bedrijf"  />
                    <option value="Voor een project" />
                    <!--De gebruiker kan kiezen tussen stage of project-->
                </datalist>
            </fieldset>
```

Comment: You have to use Javascript.

Comment: where you want to append your div?

Answer (score 0):

With this HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Ik wil mijn aanmelden:</legend>
    <input type="text" id="keuzesinput" list="keuzes" />
    <datalist id="keuzes">
        <option value="Als Stage bedrijf"  />
        <option value="Voor een project" />
        <!--De gebruiker kan kiezen tussen stage of project-->
    </datalist>
</fieldset>

<div id="mydiv">my div</div>
```

and this JavaScript snippet you can show the `div#mydiv`.

```
var myinput = document.getElementById('keuzesinput');
myinput.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    mydiv.style.display = 'inline';
});
```

When the text of the `input` changes the `change` event is triggered and the style of the div is changed.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6k6kvo5a/2/) is a jsfiddle where the div hides or shows whether the textbox has some text.

*I changed the id you gave to the input because it is not valid since it contains whitespaces and the `:` character.*

Comment: Whitespace is true but [HTML5 allows a lot more flexibility with other characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id).

Comment: when you choose for "als stage bedrijf" there comes a div with the name"project. When you choose for "voor een project" there comes another div. How do you do that, with is/else is guess?

Comment: You could do it with if/else especially if the `<datalist>` has a few number of `<option>` tags

Comment: Can anybody send me a jsfiddle how to do that with if/else?

Comment: it doesn't work. My console says "cannot read property 'adeventlistener' of null. What to do?

Comment: It is **addEventListener**